# update object attributes from two lists / python 3

Tags: python, list, object

It's few days I'm looking for a solution to my problem. 
I have a python object which has a set of arguments.

I'm reading a csv file row by row from each row I extract the values corresponding to the argument set. Those values are grouped in a list. All the csv rows do not have the same length, they can contain a minimum of 3 values and a maximum of 6 values.

What I want to do is: once my list is ready, I update the arguments value of my object with this list

example:

```
class MidiData:
#constructor
def __init__(self):
    self.Track = "0"
    self.Time = "0"
    self.Info = "0"
    self.Channel = "0"
    self.Note = "0"
    self.Velocity = "0"

dictionary=['Track','Time','Info','Channel','Note','Velocity']
mylist=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

#function I want to implement
myobject.update(mylist)

myobject.print()
```

output:

```
Track = "a"
Time = "b"
Info = "c"
Channel = "d"
Note = "e"
Velocity = "f"
```

Thanks for your help, I hope I have been complete in my explanations.

Answer (score 1):

That's where `zip` comes handy. You do something like `myobject.update(dict(zip(dictionary, mylist)))`

As for implementing the `update` method you can do something like this:

```
myobject.__dict__.update(dict(zip(dictionary, mylist))
```

But I really don't recommend doing anything with `__dict__` - if you want something with dynamic fields just use dict and not a custom class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__setattr__` in a loop to update all of those attributes by their name

```
def update(self, names, values):
    for name, value in zip(names, values):
        self.__setattr__(name, value)
```